# show dynamic result using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii1.x

In my _value form table 3 input as voltage ,type and length
AS show image.r,x,b value came from type table as type select.

[image]

Value Submit

1. page not refresh on submit
2. on submit temp result=r*length

Again when enter value and submit then show second result in below first one till user do.
on clear all result clean.
"how we can achieve using javascript append and prepend"

Comment: click on as show u will see image

Comment: add image instead of links

Comment: @ErbaAitbayev'KZ' New users cannot add images.

Comment: Ahh. Ok. Will take that into account.

Comment: Your calculation is being done on server side? via PHP or any server side technology?

Comment: replace form with div so that on submit nothing will happen anyhow you will doing javascript for submitting the values.

Comment: Your requirement were not clear. specify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

For your solution, call a javascript function on `onClick()` of Submit button and add following code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('onClick' => 'js: return submitForm(this);')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::button('Clear', array('onClick' => 'js: return clearForm(this);')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
  function submitForm(obj) {
    var r = document.getElementById("TestpageForm_r").value;
    var len = document.getElementById("TestpageForm_length").value;
    var result = 0;

    if (r != "" && len != "") {
      result = r * len;      
      var strAppend = '<div class="row"><span>Result: </span><span>' + result + '</span></div>';
      $('#mainDiv').append(strAppend);
    }
    else{
      alert('Please enter value of r and length');
    }
    return false;
  }
  function clearForm(obj) {
    document.getElementById('mainDiv').innerHTML = "";
  }
</script>
```